# Sharepoint item multilevel approval

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have a list with approvers upto 4 levels. Once an item is created Approver 1 will approve or reject it, if it is approved approver 2 will approver and same for approver 3 and 4. Is there any way to do this by list itself without using MS Flow approval.

Answer (score 2):

No, that cannot be done in the list itself. You will need either Flow or a SharePoint Designer workflow for this. If you use SharePoint online, Flow would be the better option, since it is more powerful and supports more platforms (approvals via email, approve on your mobile phone).

The flow logic you describe is pretty easy to set up in MS Flow.

If you want to run approvals in the list or library directly, you can set up extra columns for each approval, for example with a choice field of "Approved" and "Rejected" as the values. Then let the approvers edit the item properties and select the value for "their" approval column.

The version history will show you exactly who changed what column at what time.

Comment: yep I did it by using flow and its working exactly as I said, but the requirement now is that it is getting heavy for approver to check mail and then approve or reject it. so they want it into list directly

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer.